# How to force execution of value assignment in blocks of type <%=value%>

Tags: asp.net, default-value, execution, compiler-directives, page-directives

is there a directive or a instruction to force the execution of the blocks of type <%=value%> in webpages?, because i have a web project in which i have a block of that type and it just evaluates the very first time (when value is ""), but if i change the value of the variable value, which is a public field of type string, within a button the content doesn't evaluates , i am using value to insert a script. I uploaded a copy of my aspx to my web server and the code works fine, but the problem i have is that it doesn't work while i am debugging, value is never evaluated and the script block is never inserted.

I really need to be able to debug the web application with the script running to keep coding.

Regards.

P.S. I really need to use this method , because the ScriptManager's RegisterClientScriptBlock and RegisterStartupScript for me are useless on previous versions of Internet Explorer.

..........

```
    public string value = "";

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Just a silly example of a script.
        value = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(Add(3,4));</script" + ">";

    }
```

.........

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Add(number1, number2) {
        return (number1 + number2);
    }

 </script>

<%=value %>
```

Comment: How is RegisterClientScriptBlock or RegisterStartupScript useless on previous versions of IE?  What are you experiencing with this?

Comment: I just tried several times to use both instructions with the same results, the script being never inserted , if I debugged the lines of code, those were executed but the script never appeared on the page, that is why i am referring to those instructions as useless.

Answer (score 0):

aspx:

```
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

c#:

```
Literal1.Text = "<script type=\"text/javascript\">alert(Add(3,4));</script" + ">";
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: I tried your solution but incredibly the script isn't inserted, I think there is something tricky going on with my webpage. Although I think your solution is creative, it is like if my webpage execution is stuck, as you can see it cannot assign a value to a literal either :(.

Comment: instead of assigning the js string, if you assign some random string value to the Literal1.Text, will the page render the value?

Comment: Yes, I tested the literal with the initial value of "hey" and it worked, but after pressing the button it did nothing to the value of the literal, the script was not inserted.